# Seamless deployment of Django to single server

Tags: django, svn, nginx, amazon-web-services, gunicorn

I have a new website built on Django and Python 2.6 which I've deployed to the cloud (buzzword compliant AND the Amazon micro EC2 instance is free!).
Here are my detailed notes: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qcZ_SqxNcFlGKNyp-CXqcFxXXsKs26Avv3mytXGCedA/edit?hl=en_US

As this is a new site (and wanting to play with the latest and greatest) I used Nginx and Gunicorn on top of Supervisor.
All software installed from trunk using YUM / easy_install.
My database is Sqlite (for now - not sure of where to go next, but that is not the question). Also on the todo list: virtualenv + pip.
So far so good.
My code in in SVN. I wrote a simple fabfile to deploy - checks out the latest code and restarts Gunicorn via Supervisor. I hooked my DNS name to an Elastic IP.
**It works.**

My question is, how do I update the site without a disruption of service? Users of the site get 404s / 500s when I run my little update script.

Is there a way to do this without adding another server (price is key)?

I would love to have a staging system (on a different port?) and a seamless switch between Staging and Production. On the same (free) server. Via Fabric.
How do I do that? Is it the same Nginx running both sites? Can I upgrade Staging without hurting Production? What would the fabfile look like? What would the directory tree look like?

Thanks!

Tal.

Related:

- [Seamless deployment in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107615/seamless-deployment-in-rails)
  -

Comment: For anybody reading "EC2 Micro is free": it isn't really (at least not anymore). It is free for the first 750h, which is approximatevely a 20$ offer. checkout the other [ASW Free Offers](http://aws.amazon.com/free/)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx allows you to setup failover for your reverse proxies you can put one gunicorn instance as the primary and as long as that version is running it will never look at the failover.

If you configure your site so that your new version is in the failover instance you just need to write your fab file to update the failure instance with the new version of the site and then when ready, turn off primary instance. Nginx will seamlessly failover to second instance and bam you are running on new version with no downtime.

You can then update the primary version and then turn it back on and your primary is now live. At this point you can keep the failover instance running just in case, or turn it off.

Some things to consider. You have to be careful with databases, if you are using sqllite make sure both gunicorn instances can accesss the sqllite file.

If you have a normal database this is less of a problem, you just need to make sure you apply any database migrations that the new version needs before you switch to it.

If they are backwards compatible changes then it isn't a big deal. If they aren't backwards compatible then be careful, you could break the old version of the site before you switch over to new version.

To make things easier I would run the versions on different virtual environments.

If you use supervisord to control gunicorn, then you can use the supervisorctl commands to reload/restart which ever instance you want to deploy without affecting the other one.

Hope that helps

Here is an example of and nginx config (not a full config file, removed the unimportant parts)

This assumes the primary gunicorn instance is running on port 9005 and the other is running on port 9006

```
upstream service-backend {
    server localhost:9005;        # primary
    server localhost:9006 backup; # only used when primary is down
}

server {
    listen 80;
    root /opt/htdocs;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/logs/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/logs/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://service-backend;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I configure Nginx to do that? Here is my Nginx config: http://pastebin.com/xdYxPeS2  Can I have both Gunicorns running in parallel listening to different ports (Staging / Production) and still switch as you described?

Comment: added the nginx example config. Yes you can have them both running at the same time on different ports. The best way to do this is with supervisord or some other process manager.

Comment: This does allow me to have 2 gunicorns, each with different SW and have Nginx manage the switchover as I kill the running Gunicorn with 
Supervisorctl. But how can I test the backup server running the new software? It is not connected to the outside world. Isn't the only port Nginx is listening to in this configuration 80?

Comment: @Tal you can setup a second server config which runs on a different port, or the same port but different url (subdomain?) and make sure the proxy pass only uses the backup server.

Comment: @Ken but then the switchover would involve changing the nginx configuration (and restarting ngnix)??? 
Unless I have 3 gunicorns - 1 running the current SW, 1 backing it up with the new SW and 1 staging listening to a different port. I will test the staging server and if ok switch to the backup server. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Tal no you wouldn't need to change the nginx config at all. unless you want to turn off the staging server, but you could easily just shut down the guincorn instance for that, and be good. You plan sounds like it will work, you could probably do it with just two instances, but 3 is a lot safer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to figure out how to tell gunicorn to [gracefully restart](http://blog.tplus1.com/index.php/2010/12/31/how-to-restart-a-gunicorn-server-from-vim/). It seems like all you have to do is issue a HUP to the gunicorn process when to notify to reload the app. As describe in the link about, the [gunicorn docs](http://gunicorn.org/faq.html#contents) explain how to do it.

Comment: Does Gunicorn "gracefully" gracefully restart? Do all website users carry on as if nothing has happened? How does that work when Nginx sends jobs to the Gunicorn port and there is no one listening (for a brief moment)?  Also, this does not address the source code upgrade - how will the new Gunicorn instance know to run the new code?

Comment: Usually, "graceful restarts" refers to not losing any requests when restarting. I have read some material on unicorn and gunicon is a port of it. I believe requests that are in the process of being served when you issue a SIGHUP will finish up processing as your new code is spun up. Also, unicorn is designed to have the worker processes pull from a queue of requests only when the worker is "ready". This blog post mentions it: https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn ... this link describes the graceful restart feature as well: http://tomash.wrug.eu/2010/01/30/the-awesomeness-of-unicorn.html

Comment: Another thing I want to add is somewhat related to Ken's response... I would perform rolling restarts across all your upstream gunicorn servers, so that your gunicorn servers don't get overloaded with pending requests and loading new workers.