# Handling different static files between environments when deploying update to primary / fallback Django servers

Tags: django, caching, nginx, fallback

I'm following [Ken Cochrane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6423934/392143) to the question [Seamless deployment of Django to single server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6421653/392143). I'm essentially running two production servers, one `primary` and one `fallback`, and my nginx is configured as follows (omitting unnecessary details):

```
upstream app-primary {
    server localhost:12345;
    server localhost:12346 backup;
}
server {
    root /home/fraxtil/app/primary;
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/fraxtil/app/primary/static/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app-primary;
    }
}
```

When pushing an update, I upgrade `fallback`, then turn off `primary`, upgrade it, and turn it back on. The solution is *almost* perfect, but there's one problem: I'm using django-compressor to collect and compress my CSS and JS files, and the two instances aren't guaranteed to have the same static filenames. So while `primary` is down, the `fallback` server handles app requests just fine, but nginx is looking for static files in `/.../primary/static/` instead of `/.../fallback/static/`.

Is there a way to solve this problem without routing static file requests through Django? Alternatively, is there a *better* way to seamlessly deploy Django updates? (I'm interested in having zero downtime, which is why the two-server model enticed me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it work using the try_files directive. I had actually tried this before posting the question, but for some reason my first attempt made every request 404. This seems to work, though:

```
server {
    # Moved the root up one level
    root /home/fraxtil/app;
    location /static/ {
        # Try the primary instance's static folder, then the fallback's
        try_files /primary/$uri /fallback/$uri =404;
    }
...
```

The only drawback here is that all requests for nonexistent static files will hit the disk twice, but that shouldn't be too big of an issue.